# SharePoint 2013 - Health Analyzer

Tags: sharepoint-server

Which  of the following is used to collect health information about web application: SP Health Analyzer or Timer Jobs?

Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things Usage and health data collection and sharepoint health analyzer rules. It is combination of both.

Usage and health data collection and timer job.

The system writes usage and health data to the logging folder and the logging database. The usage and health data might consist of performance counter data, event log data, timer service data, metrics for site collections and sites, search usage data, or various performance aspects of the Web servers. The system uses this data to create health reports, and administrative reports.

Health Analyzer rule

SharePoint 2013 includes an integrated health analysis tool that is named SharePoint Health Analyzer that you can use to check for potential configuration, performance, and usage problems. SharePoint Health Analyzer runs predefined health rules against servers in the farm. A health rule runs a test and returns a status that tells you the outcome of the test.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748636.aspx